# BLTouch not touching bed while leveling

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, bigtreetech

I have an Ender 3 Pro that I installed a BLTouch sensor on. After I auto-home, I level bed and it deploys the probe in the right spot, but doesn't go down far enough, then goes back up and stops leveling.

I am using the wiring for BLTouch for Z homing on [SKR mini E3 v1.2](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware/V1.2). I am using Marlin Bugfix-2.0 with BLTouch and a few other things enabled.

- [Configuration Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mWt4nngrnQvXDfSZE2WamGfrVnOf-52c?usp=sharing)
- [Video of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45KrR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed everything. What I did is I used this guide <youtu.be/y_1Kg45APko> which was a guide by makes'n'breaks on setting the probe z-offset using pronterface and then reverted to the original firmware that was on this page<github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/…> Which was the marlin firmware for bltouch for z homing for my mainboard.